# Querying Mongodb by unix timestamp range

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to perform a custom query in Python via an ajax call.

The frontend sends the the start time and end time data in unix time eg `1548417600000`.
I then convert to (`ISO`) time (I think?) in Python as that is what MongoDB prefers afaik.

Document example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c125a185dea1b0252c5352"),
    "time" : ISODate("2018-12-13T15:09:42.536Z"),
}
```

PyMonogo doesn't return anything however, despite knowing that there should be thousands of results.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def querytimerange(request):
    print("Expecto Patronum!!")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        querydata = lambda x: request.POST.get(x)
        colname = querydata('colname')
        startdate = querydata('start')
        enddate = querydata('end')
        startint = int(startdate)
        endint = int(enddate)
        dtstart = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(startint/1000.0)
        iso_start = str(dtstart.isoformat())
        print(iso_start)
        dtend = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(endint/1000.0)
        iso_end = str(dtend.isoformat())
        print(iso_end)
        collection = db[colname]

        data = collection.find({"time": {"$gt": iso_start,"$lt": iso_end}})

        for a in data:
            print(a)

        return JsonResponse({"ok": "ok"})

    else:

        return JsonResponse({"ok": "no"})
```

So yeah, I think I'm struggling to get the format of the dates right.
After converting from Unix time, the date is in a str like this:

`2019-01-20T04:00:00` &
`2019-01-25T12:00:00`.

Not sure if that's correct, but that should by isoformat afaik?

Main goal is to use it in an aggregation pipeline.

```
        {
            "$match": {
                "time":{
                    "date": {
                        "$gt":startdate,
                        "$lt":enddate
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I'm using PyMongo Driver on my Django app.

Thanks!

Comment: in your schema if the `time` field is defined as `Date` type, you can query in it with the timestamp as well no need to convert.

Comment: Still no luck. 
I edited the main question with more details if it will help.